# Detect user just logged in context processor in Django

Tags: django

I need to show users some banners depending on certain situations. One of those situations is a moment, when user just logged in.

How can I detect in django 1.4 context processor login moment? I know about `django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in` signal, but I have no idea, how can I use check it in context processor.

How can I do this? Or is there another ways to detect users login event in context processor?
May be there is the way to create signal handler, which will set some variable in request object, and in context processor I would check it. Or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set session in login view, and destroy it after use.